# How do I upload my react app to a web host?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have created a react js app which works fine when I run it on local server:3000. I need to run it from the web, have signed up to Heroku, but am now not sure how to do this...

Please help.

Comment: Try reading the getting started guides at heroku

Answer (score 0):

An alternative from heroku: Netlify. You can create a github repository, push your project in there, then create an account in netlify and upload your project directly from your repository. This is by far the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> npm run build

which will create the build files in the build directory. after that, you can upload the files from the build directory to Heroku / any hosting sites.